# factory girl nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, specifications, pry

In **rails console**,I run this command

```
bill = Bill.last
bill.bill_extras
```

The result is like that.

```
[#<BillExtra id: 141, bill_id: 621, content: "extra fee", prize: #<BigDecimal:7fa2e37d4f50,'0.248E3',9(18)>, created_at: "2012-08-02 04:48:12", updated_at: "2012-08-02 04:50:41">]
```

**In spec file**,

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'pry'
describe Bill do

  before(:all) do
    @project=Factory(:project_started)
    @customer_bill=Factory(:customer_invoice, :project => @project)
    @creavite_bill=Factory(:creative_invoice, :project => @project)
    @bill_extra=Factory.build(:bill_extra, :bill => @customer_bill)
  end
  binding.pry
end
```

When I'm debugging,run these commands in pry,

```
@customer_bill.bill_extras
```

it will be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax isn't quite right there.

`FactoryGirl.create(:project_started)`

Is the way to create items.